# How to fix Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: typescript

I try to use TypeScript and I have error like that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at main.js:2
```

Here is my tsconfig.js:

```
{
    "files": [
        "source/ts/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "js",
        "rootDir": "source/ts"
    }
}
```

This error occured when I try to invoke imported function. 
Did I forget something in configuration?

Comment: Does the file that you're importing actually export anything?

Comment: I use the export default keyword.
For example: 

export default function(a: number) {
    console.log(a + 10);
}

Comment: Ok I find out, that to use functionality of importing modules I must use browserify.

Answer (score 0):

> This error occured when I try to invoke imported function. Did I forget something in configuration?

You cannot use modules (or imports) in the browser natively at the moment. Please use a module bundler e.g. webpack

## More

- A webpack TypeScript quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html